# Symfony 2.4 project deployment without SSH

Tags: php, symfony

I have made a small project with symfony 2.4 at my local system. I have uploaded all the project files to my shared hosting server with same directory structure and database. Only the name of my public directory is "public_html" instead of "web". I don't have SSH access to this server. When i run the website by typing the domain name then it shows blank page. I see below given error in my server's log file:

```
adminhelpline.com [Sun Apr 20 17:08:55 2014] [error] [client 5.10.83.33:35937]  AH01215: PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/sites/adminhelpline.com/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sites/adminhelpline.com/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
```

My Autoload file looks like this:

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit48e5d1e7fa77bf3d631b331b6343761b::getLoader();
```

Can anyone help me to sort out the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's quite simply. what the error log tells you that the file **autoload_real.php** in the folder **/home/sites/adminhelpline.com/vendor/composer** doesn't exist.

check the structure of your folders I assume you use some sort of ftp client? the worst case try to change the autoload.php not to include that file and see what you get or just move the file to the same folder as the autoload.php and change line 5 folder structure.

Comment: Thank you Sela. There was a file name case problem. Windows ignores upper and lower case but linux does not. Hence proved that symfony project can be deployed without SSH.

Comment: I'm not sure how new Windows works, but Linux and Mac case sensitive will make the difference. In old Windows it didn't matter again not sure how it's with the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `composer update` in your local machine, and then deploy the generated `vendor/` folder.

This folder will contain the dependencies and the generated autoload